# "На двух витринах выпадают/выпадает стекла.стекло"?

Tags: стилистика

Есть ли разница? Есть две витрины и на каждой выпадает стекло.
1)На двух витринах выпадают стекла.
2) На двух витринах выпадает стекло.

Comment: **shampar**, Вы внесли правку, которая изменяет смысл условия. Даже если от этого не меняется форма ответа, всё равно такая правка некорректна.

Comment: Так это мы откатим, не вопрос.

Comment: Согласен, такую правку можно делать только с согласия автора. Откатил.

Answer (score 3):

**На** витрине размещаются предметы экспозиции. А если *выпадают стёкла*, то речь идёт о стёклах, входящих в конструкцию витрины.
***В*** двух витринах выпадают стёкла.

Comment: А это мнение правильное. Хотя и несколько категоричное. Вопрос-то был о форме "стекло" или "стекла".

Comment: Hermit, речь идет о двух витринах, а не о стеклах  входящих в конструкцию витрины.

Comment: Серж, не моё конечно дело, но Вы русский язык понимаете?  У Hermita: "***В двух витринах*** выпадают стёкла".

Comment: Серж, вот мне как-то ближе во множественном числе, даже если в *каждой* витрине из двух (я бы написал в *обеих*; для 2 шт. термин всеобщности представляется завышенным) всего-навсего по одному стеклу. И даже в отсутствие собирательности у слова *дверь* я бы написал аналогично, во множественном: "В обоих домах скрипят входные двери". Или калитки. Imho.

Comment: *Серж, вот мне как-то ближе во множественном числе* - так оно и понятно, что ближе, потому что правильнее.. Только тут же Серж настаивает на *семантической* неправильности нашего с Вами выбора. Вот где собака зарыта. А логика совершенно непонятна. Если две витрины, то почему вдруг стекло одно? Было бы наоборот - еще был бы какой-то смысл в единственном числе, но одно стекло на две витрины как императивный вариант - это ни в какие учебники не лезет. Вот я все и хочу логику понять, а в ответ только и слышу "читайте учебники". Может, Вам больше повезет.

Comment: Да, еще он утверждает, что у него русский  родной, но это только с его слов.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: ***В двух витринах выпадают стекла.***

Понятно, что не на витринах, а в витринах. См. Hermit.
А по сути, лучше конечно, сказать *"выпадают стекла"*.
Поскольку стекла два, а обобщение или собирательность здесь ошибочны. "Выпадает стекло" - ошибка не грубая, но стилистически значимая. Да и по смыслу. Чтобы починить, требуется **два стекла**. Это штучный товар.

Вот "на двух предприятиях варится стекло", "два предприятия выпускают стекло" - это да, собирательность.

Comment: Это ваше мнение неправильное! Впрочем как всегда - высосанное из из пальца!

Comment: Мое мнение правильное. А насчет "высосаное" - не Вам утверждать.  "Читайте учебники" (с) - это у вас последнее время стало единственным доводом. Хочется, наконец, порекомендовать Вам последовать своему совету.

Comment: Учебники, в отличии от вас, я читаю. И, в отличии от вас, не оспариваю их правоту. Это Вы любите везде ошибки искать и доказывать, что ваши ответы единственно правильные! Так что не вам меня учить.

Comment: Плохо, значит, читаете. В *отличие* от меня. Не в коня корм.

Comment: А то и видно!...

Comment: Ну да. Видно. И не только мне, надо заметить.

Answer (score -2):

Если на каждой отдельной витрине по одному стеклу, то правильно: выпадает стекло. Если же стекол больше чем одно, тогда правильно: выпадают стекла.

Comment: Это мнение Сержа. Неправильное.